# The file upload by CloudFront Origin Access Identity signed url can't be access by boto3 or IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

I followed by cloudfront docuement http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-granting-permissions-to-oai for private file.

The bucket policy looks like:

```
{  
"Version": "2008-10-17",  
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",  
"Statement": [  
    {  
        "Sid": "1",  
        "Effect": "Allow",  
        "Principal": {  
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXX"  
        },  
        "Action": "s3:*",  
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXX/*"  
    }  
]  
}
```

When I upload file by the signed url with KEY PAIR. The file owner is

```
Owner CloudFront Origin Access Identity *********
```

At now, I can't using boto3 in ec2. The command

```
aws s3 cp s3::/xxx/uploadfile test.txt
```

Give me a error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

I can upload file which don't use the signed url. These file can be access by boto3 fine. These file owner is

```
 ****MyCountName*****
```

So I can't figure out why `ec2` machine can't head the `origin access identity` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, when the CloudFront Origin Access Identity (OAI) authorizes the upload, the OAI is the entity that owns the object -- not your account.

```
Owner CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXX
```

OAIs represent an entity that you exclusively control, but they aren't actually part of your AWS account.

The ownership of an object is determined by the account that authorizes the upload, not the account that owns the bucket.  Accounts other than the uploading account must be given permission by the account that owns the object.

```
x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

You can make this header mandatory using bucket policy.

If you control the client that makes the uploads, you should be able to add this header.

If you don't control the client, you *should* be able to add it with a Lambda@Edge Viewer Request trigger.  I have not tested this code, but it should accomplish the purpose:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  if(request.method == 'PUT')
  {
    request.headers['x-amz-acl'] = [
      { key: 'x-amz-acl', value: 'bucket-owner-full-control' }
    ];
  }
  return callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: try it and it work. thanks . I should read document more carefully.

Comment: There is a problem I think. The `Origin Access Identity` is the owner of the object uploaded. When you don't want delete the object from s3 but want disable access by the `cloudfront` seem no way.  Because the owner can always read the object.

Comment: @jiamo you can change the owner of an object by copying the object onto itself.  The account issuing the copy command becomes the owner, which would allow the bucket owner to take ownership away from the OAI.

Comment: `k = s3c.head_object(Bucket='test', Key='test')
m = k["Metadata"]
s3c.copy_object(Bucket='test',  Key='test', CopySource={'Bucket'='test', Key='test'}, Metadata=m, MetadataDirective='REPLACE') 
`  seem don't change the owner.

Comment: @jiamo that is unexpected.  Did it change the `Last-Modified` timestamp?  It should, if worked.

Comment: My mistake. It indeed change the owner. even if don't change `Last-Modified`.  Now I am confused. After change the owner. The cloudfont url with origin access identiy and only http get configured should can't read the object.  while the cdn url still can  download.  If I using `s3.generate_presigned_post` and make it public. When delete I make it private.(This workflow may be easy than the OAI workflow)

Comment: I just remember there is a good place to use `OAI workflow`. The client may upload file fast than the `s3 presigned url`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload a file to S3 or download a file from S3? Because you mentioned this command *aws s3 cp s3::/xxx/uploadfile test.txt* which downloads a file not upload and this is an *aws-cli* command not boto3.

Please look at this documentation here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Also if you look at the IAM policy, it's granting GetObject permission to CloudFront OAI user only.