# Uploaded S3 file from CloudFront can't access

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

It may look a little strange that I want to upload file to S3 bucket through cloudfront, and access it with CloudFront.

And AWS declared that CloudFront support this putObject action according to
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/
Now we have configured the CloudFront settings(Origin/Behavior) and S3 policy to complete this.
Only one block issue found that:
The uploaded file via CloudFront can't be accessed by any account or any roles. It's owner named "cf-host-credentials-global".

Just tried several ways to fix this issue, base on a quite simple solution:
CloudFront can access the S3 bucket(This s3 bucket is not public accesible.) with OAC which has putObject and getObject permission on it.
We can use a CloudFront URL mapping to S3 bucket origin for uploading a file.
Note: No signed CloudFront or signed S3 URL, but I also tested those cases actually.

We still always get such accessDenied issue, most of time it can be uploaded with the expected size and file name.
But it can't be downloaded or accesible.

I endeavor to fix this on this simple solution, but all of them are failed as below:

1. add x-amz-acl header, according to answer on stackoverflow
   [The file upload by CloudFront Origin Access Identity signed url can't be access by boto3 or IAM role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572484/the-file-upload-by-cloudfront-origin-access-identity-signed-url-cant-be-access)

- I add the x-amz-acl header, but got this error with failed uploading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message>
    <HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-acl</HeadersNotSigned>
    <RequestId>NDOLGKOGSF883</RequestId>
    <HostId>CD9cDmGbSuk34Gy3mK2Znfdd9klmfew0s2dsflks3</HostId>
</Error>
```

- Even use a pre-signed S3 url(put the x-amz-acl header in boto3 generate_presigned_url), it still the same error.

2. seems someone said x-amz-acl can be put into query parameter, then I have tried it in the URL(with signed URL and unsigned URL), it doesn't work anyway.
   [Pre-signed URLs and x-amz-acl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895775/pre-signed-urls-and-x-amz-acl)
3. someone said we need to add x-amz-content-sha256 header in the client request, according to
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4

- add x-amz-content-sha256 header, it can be uploaded successfully, but still failed with `AccessDenied` on that S3 Object uploaded.
- add Content-MD5 header, it got the issue that header is not signed as above, and uploading failed.

Anyone has an idea about this? How to fix this `AccessDenied` issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think I also have this problem and solved.
[You don't have permissions to get object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/715cN.png)
Owner of Object is Cloudfront OAI/OAC. So, you can't get/list this object. You need to change Ownership section to AWS Root Account.

In Permissions Tab of Bucket, Go to Object Ownership section. switch from "ACLs enable" to "ACLs Disable" [edit Object Owership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luUgi.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like x-amz-acl header via OAC is not getting signed when the request is being sent from CloudFront to S3 bucket.
So if you insist on using OAC, there's only one way: change the "Object Ownership" to ACLs disabled in S3 bucket permissions.
And that works for me.